# Redis Vector Radius Search

Tags: vector, redis

I saw in the [Redis document](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/query/vector-search/#radius) that querying all vectors within a given radius is supported, but my use case is to just get the number/count of vectors which are within the given radius, what is the most efficient way to achieve my use case with Redis vector capabilities? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `LIMIT 0 0` at the end of your query or within the optional query arguments.

From [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/ft.search/):

> **LIMIT first num**
>
> ... You can use `LIMIT 0 0` to count the number of documents in the
> result set without actually returning them.